# Adding a websocket "put" request in the bootstrap.js file in sails : cannot find io

Tags: sockets, sails.js

I need to call a socket request from the bootstrap.js file in sails.
The bootstrap.js file has some code checking if some game engine has updated some file. If so, it needs send a message with some updated data via socket to some defined route called "/update"... e.g.

```
io.socket.put('/update', {history:{sessions:[1,2,3,4]}},function gotResponse(body, response) {
    console.log('Server sending request ot server ');
})
```

The problem is that it tells me that io is not recognised.
I tried to do npm install for both sails.io.js and socket.io-client and then write:

```
var io = require('sails.io.js')( require('socket.io-client') );
```

at the top.
Unfortunately, it gives me the following error message:

```
C:\Users\Evolver\Documents\programming\pipegame\game6\node_modules\socket.io-client\lib\url.js:29
if (null == uri) uri = loc.protocol + '//' + loc.host;
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
at url (C:\Users\Evolver\Documents\programming\pipegame\game6\node_modules\socket.io-client\lib\url.js:29:29)
at lookup (C:\Users\Evolver\Documents\programming\pipegame\game6\node_modules\socket.io-client\lib\index.js:44:16)
at goAheadAndActuallyConnect (C:\Users\Evolver\Documents\programming\pipegame\game6\node_modules\sails.io.js\sails.io.js:835:21)
at selfInvoking (C:\Users\Evolver\Documents\programming\pipegame\game6\node_modules\sails.io.js\sails.io.js:812:18)
at SailsSocket.SailsIOClient.SailsSocket._connect (C:\Users\Evolver\Documents\programming\pipegame\game6\node_modules\sails.io.js\sails.io.js:831:9)
at null._onTimeout (C:\Users\Evolver\Documents\programming\pipegame\game6\node_modules\sails.io.js\sails.io.js:1463:17)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. 
It now works, once npm install has been done for socket.io-client and sails.io.js if I do exactly the following:

```
var socketIOClient = require('socket.io-client');
var sailsIOClient = require('sails.io.js');

// Instantiate the socket client (`io`)
var io = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient);
io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337';

// then I send something via my socket
io.socket.put('/update', {history:{sessions:[1,2,3,4]}},function gotResponse(body, response) {
                    console.log('Server sending request ot server ');
                })
```